# Algorithm or formula to find good tuning values for searching

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a programming search problem and I am wondering if there are any algorithm, class, formula or procedure that can produce good search locations based on past results.   (I’m guessing there is somewhere.) Or, would the solution I threw out there be good?

Let me try to explain with a simple example: Say there is a pond that that is 2 X 2 meters and 3 meters deep.  I can basically put my fishing lure at any of the x,y,z locations (2 X 2 X 3 = 27 locations).  Say I fish at each location for one hour (testing out the pond) and I ketch a different amount of fish at each of the 27 locations. Now, after I do that, the best place to logically fish is the location I caught the most fish BUT just because I caught the most fish there it does not mean it’s the best spot.  I could have just been lucky.  It would probably might be better to spend a big chunk of my time at that location but still adventure out a percentage of the time to confirm that is the best place.

One simple (and bad?) solution is just to fish 10 hour in every location and wherever the most fish are caught would probably be a good location but that would be a lot of wasted time(270 hours). Chances are if I ketch 15 finish at some x,y,z and none at x2,y2,z2 then I should not spend much time at the x2,y2,z2.

A second solution I was thinking about was to keep a tally of the hours spent and total fish caught at each location. And then do something like: (simple example)

```
float catchesByLocation[2,2,3] = {1}; //init all to 1
float totalTimeSpentByLocation[2,2,3] = {1}; //init all to 1

While(true) //never really ends
{
  Do x = 0 to 2 
    Do y = 0 to 2 
      Do z = 0 to 3  //depth
      {
        float timeToSpendAtThisLoc = catchesByLocation[x,y,z] / totalTimeSpentByLocation[x,y,z];
        float catches = GoFishing(x,y,z);
        catchesByLocation[x,y,z] = catchesByLocation[x,y,z] + catches;
        totalTimeSpentByLocation[x,y,z] = totalTimeSpentByLocation[x,y,z] + timeToSpendAtThisLoc;
      }
}
```

With this solution, some amount of time will always be spend on the bad locations but as time goes on the bad locations will get a very small fraction of the total time.

So the question I have - is there some logical approach to do this?  Maybe there is even an exact correct way to solve this using math? Any thoughts on ways to attack this problem?  Sorry for the bad title, I cannot think of how to title it and am open to suggestions. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: 1) do some abstraction. merge (x,y,z) to a single location. 2) `GoFishing(location, timeToSpendAtThisLoc)` 3) fix the math so that you use proper weights, and numbers have meaning (units!) 4) do you assume that the probability distribution is fixed? if so, after a while you don't need to check bad places. if not, you need the process to be able to forget old data.

Comment: Thank you Karoly for the input.  The distribution will change but I thought it would best to leave that out of my question to keep it shorter.  I like your thoughts on the abstraction part.  I guess the whole 3 dimension thing does not really apply since each block is independent.  I'll spend some time thinking about the problem with just some number of buckets where size does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fish pond problem describes an instance of a class of problems called *Explore/Exploit* algorithms, or *Multi-Armed Bandit* problems; see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit. There is a large body of mathematical theory and algorithmic approaches, however the key assumptions are roughly as follows:

- Fishing at the location where we have seen the highest number of
  fish/hour optimizes the expected short term reward (this is what we should do if we had only one hour). However, if we continue fishing over some time, there might be better spots, but we have insufficient information.
- To formalize this thought, we introduce a time discount (a fish
  caught today is more valuable than one caught tomorrow, say, by a factor of 0.8). Our goal is
  to maximize the total discounted fish, over a set period of fishing,
  or over an infinite horizon.
- Every hour, we decide whether to fish in the current best location, or to obtain more information on a new one. The simplest possible strategy ("epsilon-greedy") would fish at the currently best-looking location e.g. with probability 90%, and select another location randomly 10% of the time.
- More sophisticated strategies would introduce a probability estimate that a location can be better than our current best location (this depends both on the estimate's expected value and its variance; i.e., total time spent, and fish/hour). Then, we base the decision on this probability, for a more informed choice (explore spots first that look most promising so far).
- For the fish pond problem, a reasonable probability model might take neighborhood into account (locations (x,y,z) is likely similar to location (x-1,y,z), (x,y-1,z), etc).

Comment: Thank you Stefan!  I knew there had to be something like this.  The Multi-armed Bandit problem probably exactly describes my problem. I'll spend some time looking into it.